# I need to pull data from a .txt file that is inconsistent with delimters

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm currently working on pulling a data set from .txt files. The data set has two types of spacing that are not uniform or consistent. For example one row will be:

```
10  0  1  10
```

and the next will be:

```
10  0  1 -10
```

This is giving me errors as using `numpy.loadtxt(Data, delimeter='  ')` will sometimes create 4 columns per row, and other times 3 columns per row if there is a negative integer.

I tried to take the raw `.txt` file and replace the ' -' with '  -' so the delimeter will pick it up but I get the error `line 533, in open raise IOError("%s not found." % path)`

Any help is greatly appreciated!

My Current Code:

```
Raw_02 = open('IEA-15-240-RWT_AeroDyn15_Polar_02.txt', 'r')
Raw_02 = Raw_02.read().replace(' -', '  -')
data_02 = np.loadtxt(Raw_02, delimiter='  ', skiprows=54, dtype=str, max_rows=200) #error here
data_02_a = np.array(data_02)
data_tab_02 = pd.DataFrame(data_02_a, columns=col_names2)
data_tab_02.to_excel('Raw_Data02.xlsx', sheet_name='02')
```

Comment: The error message means that it could not find the file at the path specified.

Comment: One suggestion: have you tried `pd.read_csv(filename, delimiter=' ')? Also, can you display in code blocks the exact rows that are giving you problems, so we can reproduce and suggest help on our end?

Comment: The file path has changed when I replaced the ' -' with '  -' so I'm wondering how I can get back to where I'll be able to use numpy.loadtxt, 'Raw_02 is currently a str and not a file anymore I think.

Comment: TC Arlen, thank you! I went back and used delim_whitespace for pd.read_csv that seems to have worked for both the double space and the single spaced columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is due to the fact that `np.loadtxt` expects a `file path, not a string`.
The file can be replaced with `io.StringIO`

```
from io import StringIO
Raw_02 = open('IEA-15-240-RWT_AeroDyn15_Polar_02.txt', 'r')
Raw_02 = StringIO(Raw_02.read().replace(' -', '  -'))
data_02 = np.loadtxt(Raw_02, delimiter='  ', skiprows=54, dtype=str, max_rows=200) #error here
data_02_a = np.array(data_02)
data_tab_02 = pd.DataFrame(data_02_a, columns=col_names2)
data_tab_02.to_excel('Raw_Data02.xlsx', sheet_name='02')
```

But I think, that you should also pay attention to the fact that when replacing  `-` with   `-` the separator between other columns may not be correct.